# Life cycle of an IntentService if it also have a BackgroundThread

Tags: android, intentservice, background-thread

I have a task, which should happen sequentially. Post-processing it should do few tasks parallelly. 
I am using BackgroundThread in IntentService. 
is this a good approach or should I take any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the right solution to me. If you start a background thread for each Intent you will get the parallel behaviour you want. If you are doing a lot of these, you might want to use a ThreadPool as creating Threads is pretty expensive.